# Best way to make a list of rows and column in wxpython with each row having buttons in last column?

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, wxpython

I want to make a list of n rows with m columns.  Last column must contain a button which on clicking deletes the entire row which that button belongs to.

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFWYr.jpg) to see my desired GUI.

I have already looked for wx.grid and didn't get any success.

My questions are

1. Can this be achieved by using wx.ListCtrl?. If yes then how?
2. Which is the best wx widget other than wx.grid to achieve this.

Any sample code or illustration will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: lookup the UltimateListCtrl, there's plenty of examples of things similar to what you're describing

Comment: I searched for it and got a [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24485276/wxpython-ultimatelistctrl-check-tick-listitem-programatically) .

 I copied that and ran on my system, but i got some error. 

Error-> PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "strcmp(setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL), "C") == 0" failed at ..\..\src\common\intl.cpp(1449) in wxLocale::GetInfo(): You probably called setlocale() directly instead of using wxLocale and now there is a mismatch between C/C++ and Windows locale.
Things are going to break, please only change locale by creating wxLocale objects to avoid this!

Comment: Do i have to install some external module/packages? I am working on py 2.7

Comment: @user2682863 : Inside C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\lib\agw i already have ultimatelistctrl.py file .

Then what is the meaning of above described error. Thanks in advance.